# Are there rules for valid Maven developer roles?

Tags: java, maven

Maven supports `<developers>` with `<roles>`, however, I see no official list of valid roles.

Are these roles just plain text for documentation purposes? If there is no official list of roles to choose from, are there any rules or standards on how to format role names?

For example, is a UI developer a `uideveloper`, a `ui-developer`, a `UI Developer`, etc.

Comment: "awesomedeveloper"...

Comment: There's no official list. For example, Maven's tests and examples are oriented around the Apache organisational structure: Committer, Developer, Founder, PMC Chair, PMC Member, Release Manager, contrib, devel. None of this is enforced by schema or code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I see in the XSD. Role is just a plain `xs:string` and it is mainly used for documentation.

```xsd
<xs:element name="roles" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation source="version">3.0.0+</xs:documentation>
    <xs:documentation source="description">
        The roles the contributor plays in the project. Each role is described by a <code>role</code> element, the body of which is a role name. This can also be used to describe the contribution.
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="role" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not for specific list of developers. It is for the information about the developer who have worked on the project. It is not necessary have the specific list from where you can choose. **It is mainly used for documentation.**

> All projects consist of files that were created, at some time, by a person. Like the other systems that surround a project, so to do the people involved with a project have a stake in the project. Developers are presumably members of the project's core development. Note that, although an organization may have many developers (programmers) as members, it is not good form to list them all as developers, but only those who are immediately responsible for the code. A good rule of thumb is, if the person should not be contacted about the project, they need not be listed here.

Refer http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Developers

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules, as to my knowledge. These are plain test and are used to produce `html` when invoking the `site` goal. The result produces `team-list` HTML page like [this one](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/team-list.html).

I would suggest using human-readable text.

It's free-text and unchecked because imagine if the Apache Maven people had to keep a list of all possible positions/roles and maintain them. That would be a huge effort for nothing, as different companies tend to have different titles for the same role.