# What is the use of <developers> tag in pom.xml file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is there any special significant of using "developers"
 tag in pom.xml file or we just use it to list developers of the project.

Answer (score 4):

From `Maven` doc,

> All projects consist of files that were created, at some time, by a person. Like the other systems that surround a project, so to do the people involved with a project have a stake in the project. Developers are presumably members of the project's core development. Note that, although an organization may have many developers (programmers) as members, it is not good form to list them all as developers, but only those who are immediately responsible for the code. A good rule of thumb is, if the person should not be contacted about the project, they need not be listed here.

Refer https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Developers for more information.

Source : [Are there rules for valid Maven developer roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449142/are-there-rules-for-valid-maven-developer-roles/19449239#19449239)

Answer (score 2):

This is description by [Maven- POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Developers)

> All projects consist of files that were created, at some time, by a
>   person. Like the other systems that surround a project, so to do the
>   people involved with a project have a stake in the project. Developers
>   are presumably members of the project's core development. Note that,
>   although an organization may have many developers (programmers) as
>   members, it is not good form to list them all as developers, but only
>   those who are immediately responsible for the code. A good rule of
>   thumb is, if the person should not be contacted about the project,
>   they need not be listed here.

Answer to your question: Developer tag is use for listing developers in your organisation.

Comment: @DarshanPatel - So are you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19449239/1026459